# How to install older version of GCC on Windows 10

Tags: windows, gcc, mingw

I need to install MinGW GCC 7.3 on my computer for a project.  Downloaded and installed: C:\MinGW\bin\MingGW-get.exe.  But when I run it, it only gives me the option to install the latest GCC v9.2.0.  How do I download and install GCC v7.3 on my computer?  Step-by-step directions appreciated.  [image]

Answer (score 4):

Unless you specifically want the mingw.org toolchain, check out https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/.  Currently there's v8.1.0, v7.3.0, v6.4.0 and v5.4.0.  Other versions are available elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Of you need to support an older C/C++ standard the `-std=` compiler flag may already help (e.g. `-std=c99` for ISO 1999 C or `-std=c++98` for ISO 1998 C++).

Note that GCC 7.3 is not the latest version of GCC 7. The latest GCC 7 release is version 7.5.0.
You can the Windows (MinGW-w64) version from: http://winlibs.com/

Answer (score 0):

The online installer tool (first option on the page) allows you to do so.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe